# Flask API endpoint not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-restful

I created a flask application where in my `app.py` file I created and registered a blueprint which I used in my `routes.py` file.

This is the directory structure of my flask project:

```
stage_two_task/
   data/
      __init__.py
      persons.db
      resource.py
   routes/
      __init__.py
      routes.py
   app.py
```

## Code snippets:

resource.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, Float, Boolean
import os

# Configurations
app = Flask(__name__)
base_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(base_directory, "persons.db")

# Initialization
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

routes.py

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from stage_two_task.app import api


@api.route('/hi', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    return jsonify(message='Hello World')
```

app.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
from data.resource import app

api = Blueprint('api', __name__)
app.register_blueprint(api, url_prefix='/api')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My app instantiation was done in my `resource.py` file and in order to use it, I imported it in my `app.py` file. In `app.py` I defined and registered my blueprint which I called in `routes.py` using `from stage_two_task.app import api`

To test if my code works, I ran the app and visited `localhost:5000/api/hi`but I got a 404 page. When I run my app, I have no errors but don't get my expected message when I navigate to that specific URL.

I also added `print(app.url_map)` in my `app.py` file to see my defined URL rules but this is what i got:

```
Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> static>])
```

Comment: What do you get from `print(app.url_map)` before `app.run()`?

Comment: @roganjosh

I get `Map([<Rule '/static/<filename>' (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD) -> static>])`

Comment: Then something is missing from your question (perhaps how you defined `app`). But clearly, _no_ routes exist, let alone one from your blueprint

Comment: For a start you have `from stage_two_task.app` and `from data.resource import app` so they could be entirely different things

Comment: @roganjosh

In `stage_two_task` i have 2 packages `data` and `routes`. 
The former is where I created my database models. It has 3 files: `__init__.py, persons.db, resource.py`. resource.py contains my database definition and my app flask app instantiation. The latter package has 2 files which are `__init__.py` and `routes.py'. Sill inside`stage_two_task`, I have my `app.py` file

Comment: [edit] your question. It will be illegible in a comment

Comment: Yep, illegible. I was too slow

Comment: Ok let me do that

Comment: @roganjosh

I have just edited my question. Please look again